# Getting autoload to work for repository package

Tags: composer-php

I've tried everything classmap, psr-0, psr-4 but can't seem to get autoload to work for the when using a package from a git repository

```
{
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "package",
      "package": {
        "name": "michaeljs1990/bitcoin-php-api",
        "version": "dev-master",
        "source": {
          "url": "https://github.com/michaeljs1990/Bitcoin-PHP-API",
          "type": "git",
          "reference": "master"
        },
        "autoload": {
          "psr-0": {"Bitcoin": "src/Bitcoin"}
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "michaeljs1990/bitcoin-php-api": "dev-master"
  }
}
```

The class is defined in src/Bitcoin directory using namespace Bitcoin but this always fails

```
<?php

include 'vendor/autoload.php';

$test = new \Bitcoin\Bitcoin($null);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repository you are referring already has a `composer.json` file, so there is no need to use `type:package` for your entry in `repositories`, it is easier to simply use:

```
{
    "type": "vcs",
    "url": "https://github.com/michaeljs1990/Bitcoin-PHP-API"
}
```

This will use the Composer data directly from that repository, and it will work, because you declare the autoloading wrong:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {"Bitcoin": "src/Bitcoin"}
},
```

The original one:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
},
```

For optimal performance, this should be used:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "Bitcoin": "src/" }
},
```

What's the difference? PSR-0 needs the prefix it should try to search, and the directory from which to start searching for the complete classname converted into a pathname. A class named `Bitcoin\Bitcoin` will be expected in the relative path `Bitcoin/Bitcoin.php`.

Your autoloading told Composer that classes with `Bitcoin` could be found in `src/Bitcoin`, which is wrong for this class: `src/Bitcoin/` + `Bitcoin/Bitcoin.php` does not exist.

The original autoloading tells Composer that ANY class may be found in `src/`, which is also wrong for most of them, but true for that Bitcoin class. Even though this works, it will try to search for plenty of other classes inside that directory before searching in different directories, thus wasting disk I/O.

My suggested optimum restricts this directory to classes starting with `Bitcoin`.

Comment: This worked but I had to create a new directory then run composer install.  It seems running composer update after changing only the autoload in composer.json does not work.  Is there a re-install everything command?

Comment: Composer has the tendency to stick to whatever has already been installed. For a complete restart, delete both the `vendor` folder and the `composer.lock` file, and then run either `composer update` or `composer install` (which is the same as update if the lock file does not exist).